# Having trouble with string.Replace / Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, string

I have a sql query like this:

```
UPDATE StockUpdateQueue SET Synced = 1, SyncedAt = GETDATE() WHERE Id IN (@p0,@p1);
```

This query is dynamically generated. What I want to do is run it through a function, which will effectively replace all the `@pN` parameters with their corresponding values.

I have tried to do this with standard `string.Replace` as well as `Regex.Replace` with no luck - the replace is not taking place.

This is what I tried so far:

```
class Program
{
    static string _lastQuery;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sqlQuery = "UPDATE StockUpdateQueue SET Synced = 1, SyncedAt = GETDATE() WHERE Id IN (@p0,@p1);";
        var sqlParamters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "@p0", 12345 },
            { "@p1", 65432 }
        };

        LogLastQuery(sqlQuery, sqlParamters);
    }

    static void LogLastQuery(string sqlQuery, Dictionary<string, object> sqlParamters = null)
    {
        _lastQuery = sqlQuery;
        if (sqlParamters != null && sqlParamters.Count > 0)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> sqlParamter in sqlParamters)
                _lastQuery = Regex.Replace(
                    _lastQuery, 
                    "\\@" + sqlParamter.Key,
                    sqlParamter.Value.GetType() == typeof(int) || sqlParamter.Value.GetType() == typeof(decimal)
                        ? sqlParamter.Value.ToString() 
                        : "'" + sqlParamter.Value.ToString() + "'");
    }
}
```

I want the function to do the parameter replace and ideally output something like this:

```
UPDATE StockUpdateQueue SET Synced = 1, SyncedAt = GETDATE() WHERE Id IN (12345,65432);
```

Any ideas?

---

### Update

I use the `sqlQuery` and `sqlParamters` just as user `un-lucky` has shown, i.e.

```
{
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParamter .Key, sqlParamter.Value);
}
```

It turns out, I have been generating the dictionary keys without the `@` and .NET has been automatically adding them for me (when they are missing - as explained by user `juharr`).

Sometimes, I generate the sql query and parameters dynamically - where the list of keys and their corresponding values were generated in a `for`/`foreach` loop. This resulted in a case of mix usage going on.

So, to handle this - I've updated my function like this and it's working as intended:

```
internal void LogLastQuery(string sqlQuery, Dictionary<string, object> sqlParamters = null)
{
    _lastQuery = sqlQuery;
    if (sqlParamters != null && sqlParamters.Count > 0)
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> sqlParamter in sqlParamters)
            _lastQuery = Regex.Replace(
                _lastQuery,
                (sqlParamter.Key.ToString()[0] != '@' ? "\\@" : "") + sqlParamter.Key,
                sqlParamter.Value.GetType() == typeof(int) || sqlParamter.Value.GetType() == typeof(decimal)
                    ? sqlParamter.Value.ToString()
                    : "'" + sqlParamter.Value.ToString() + "'");
}
```

This now deals with both cases. I am not sure if this is the best method, but it works fine for now.

Comment: Explain the down vote please.

Comment: Some people are pissed of if humans are making (for those) stupid simple mistakes. However I do not think, that downvoting without critism is the right way (I'm not the downvoter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your key in dictionary already has "@" symbol, try use `sqlParamter.Key` instead of `"\\@" + sqlParamter.Key`.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to create SqlCommand with that query and add those values as parameters will be the best option for you to execute the query, instead for replacement; which means you can try something like this:

```
 var sqlQuery = "UPDATE StockUpdateQueue SET Synced = 1, SyncedAt = GETDATE() WHERE Id IN (@p0,@p1);";
 var sqlParamters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
      { "@p0", 12345 },
      { "@p1", 65432 }
 };
 SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery , conSQL); // conSQL is the connection
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> sqlParamter in sqlParamters)
 {
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParamter .Key, sqlParamter.Value);
 }
 mySqlCommand .ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: hi. I am doing exactly this already. but in the event of an exception occuring, I wanted to see what was the last sql query that ran and if any params were present, what those values were, so i wrote this `LogLastQuery` function.

Comment: @Latheesan: cool the go ahead with `Jiří Gluškov`'s answer. happy coding

Comment: @Latheesan Why not just log the query and the parameters separately

Comment: I just noticed something odd. In my original question, I've actually got a typo. In my real app, I was actually doing this: `var sqlParamters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "p0", 12345 },
            { "p1", 65432 }
        };` and this was somehow getting executed, even though I had no `@` for my dictionary keys when I did: `mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParamter .Key, sqlParamter.Value);` Strange.

Comment: @Latheesan Not sure about `mySqlParamter`, but when creating `SqlParamter` if you leave off the "@" in the name it will automatically add it for you.